# How to Use Recursive Relation in Laravel?

Tags: database, laravel, recursion, recursive-query, laravel-request

I'm using one User table to store the information of three different users. I created the parent first with one parent_id, and now I want to create the student, and I want to give reference of parent id.

My Table has an id, parent_id, name, job, etc. When the parent gets registered, it will set a new id, parent_id, name, job. When the student gets registered, it will set the new id, name, and parent_id stored earlier.

I'm new to Laravel 5.7 and I m having issues with syntaxes to store parent record with student record.

Comment: first create parent record get its id as parent_id for sudent, than create student record

Comment: I m doing the same but how will it be done with student ? how can I use same id again in other record please elobrate

Comment: means you want to make student also as parent of any other user. if yes can i see your form fields.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to make a user parent of other users. For example a student will have a parent which is also a user. If that is the case you will need your user model to be implemented like below:

```
class User extends Model
{
     public function parent(){
           return $this->belongsTo('App\User','parent_id');
     }
     public function children(){
           return $this->hasMany('App\User','parent_id');
     }
}
```

This way you can access children and parent of your users.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ali Mrj Use Ali Mrj style to make relation..

```
class User extends Model
{
  public function parent(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','parent_id');
  }
  public function children(){
       return $this->hasMany('App\User','parent_id');
  }
}
```

then you use umefarooq style to insert data.
create parent record get its id as parent_id for sudent, then create student record

how can you get the last id? it depends on your style. 
i thinking about 2 solution right now..

> 1. get all of id_parent then use it in
> 2. get the last id parent from database.

how to get last id_parent?

```
$last_user = User::where('job','teacher')->orderBy('id','desc')->get()
```